# affect a path of a file name with spaces in it in Assembly language

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, assembly

```
       assume cs :code , ds:data

data segment

aa db 'C:\Program',32,'Files\Internet',32,'Explorer\a',00h
;aa db 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\a',00h

data ends


    code segment

    main:
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax
    mov ah,41h
    lea dx,aa
    int 21h
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

    code ends
    end main
```

as you can see the path of Internet explorer has some spaces in it which make it difficult to delete
can you suggest a way to be able to use a path with spaces ? 
i'm trying to delete IE giving the fact it's being used by a virus to send my informations somewhere

Comment: Am I correct in thinking you are trying to write a piece of assembly code to delete IE from your computer?

If something is using IE maliciously, I strongly suggest you tackle the root of the problem and use standard tools/software to remove/clean the malicious software.

Comment: I did try to track it to the root but each time I think I got rid of it I find it somewhere else, the virus is reproducing quickly it runs IE to send my info, I assumed since I don't use IE it wont be a problem

Comment: why use assembly to do the job, let alone 16 bit dos code?  use a batch file, or command line, or 32 bit code using the win32 api in any language including assembly.

Comment: @Gunner: The virus won't expect a 16-bit defense tool, so it won't have any counter measures!